# Set parent by property

Tags: unity, physics, transformation

In the editor's hierarchy, if I drag and drop one object onto another, the second becomes the parent of the first, and moving the parent will cause the child to move. I see I can set this relationship in code by setting the `transform.parent` property. So I wrote a component to help with doing that from code:

```
public class ParentTo: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _parent;

    public GameObject Parent {
        get { return _parent; }
        set {
            this.transform.parent = value.transform;
            this._parent = value;
            Debug.Log("Set parent");
        }
    }
}
```

So to test it, I have 2 cubes in the scene. On cube 2 I put the ParentTo script, leaving it with no parent set, then start the game and use the editor to drop Cube 1 on that field in the inspector. According to the inspector, it seems to have been set right, but the debug statement doesn't appear in the console and moving Cube 1 doesn't move Cube 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, do you call method parent of your script?

Comment: In other code? No, I thought assigning the parent in the inspector would hit the setter. Is that the issue?

Comment: Comment the method code, save and return to the unity inspector and verify, you should continue to see the variable "Parenst" to assign